# Can't running CordaV4 from intellij

Tags: corda

1.I downloaded from "git clone https://github.com/corda/samples"

2.I open project from Intellij As the page(https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#downloading-the-example-cordapp) shows

3.I selected "Run Example Cordapp - Kotlin",And start Debugging

4.I get some exception from Intellij console

I access "web address",But it's doesn't work.

I guess server not working.

How can I solve this Exeption?

```
[INFO] 14:02:57,980 [driver-pool-thread-0] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: /Users/shintakahashi/00_dev/Corda/Project/v4_0/samples/cordapp-example/build/node-driver/20190523-050248.830/NotaryService
[INFO] 14:02:58,701 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node Notary Service, debug port is not enabled
[INFO] 14:03:14,211 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 2278 msec
[INFO] 14:03:14,356 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10000], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH], platformVersion=4, serial=1558587790286), WebAddress: localhost:10003
[INFO] 14:03:14,397 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: /Users/shintakahashi/00_dev/Corda/Project/v4_0/samples/cordapp-example/build/node-driver/20190523-050248.830/PartyA
[INFO] 14:03:14,405 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyA, debug port is not enabled
[INFO] 14:03:14,432 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: /Users/shintakahashi/00_dev/Corda/Project/v4_0/samples/cordapp-example/build/node-driver/20190523-050248.830/PartyB
[INFO] 14:03:14,437 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyB, debug port is not enabled
[INFO] 14:03:14,461 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: /Users/shintakahashi/00_dev/Corda/Project/v4_0/samples/cordapp-example/build/node-driver/20190523-050248.830/PartyC
[INFO] 14:03:14,466 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyC, debug port is not enabled
[INFO] 14:03:46,220 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Failed Startup took 51 msec
[INFO] 14:03:46,220 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10013
 net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:218) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:93) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:193) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:392) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:375) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:344) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:170) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:79) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:206) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:216) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    ... 18 more
[INFO] 14:03:46,220 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.RPCClient. - Failed Startup took 51 msec
[INFO] 14:03:46,220 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10009
 net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:218) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:93) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:193) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:392) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:375) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:344) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:170) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:79) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:206) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:216) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    ... 18 more
[INFO] 14:03:46,635 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Failed Startup took 3 msec
[INFO] 14:03:46,635 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10005
 net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:218) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:93) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:193) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:392) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:375) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:344) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:170) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:79) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:206) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:216) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    ... 18 more
[INFO] 14:03:46,724 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.RPCClient. - Failed Startup took 4 msec
[INFO] 14:03:46,724 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10013
 net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:218) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:93) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:193) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:392) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:375) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:344) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:170) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:79) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:206) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:216) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    ... 18 more
[INFO] 14:03:47,139 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.RPCClient. - Failed Startup took 3 msec
[INFO] 14:03:47,139 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10005
 net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:218) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:93) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:193) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:392) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:375) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:344) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:170) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:79) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:206) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:216) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    ... 18 more
[INFO] 14:03:49,350 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 2629 msec
[INFO] 14:03:49,712 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 2484 msec
[INFO] 14:03:50,043 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 693 msec
[INFO] 14:03:50,759 [rpc-client-observation-pool-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10004], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB], platformVersion=4, serial=1558587823861), WebAddress: localhost:10007
[INFO] 14:03:50,780 [rpc-client-observation-pool-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10008], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=4, serial=1558587823332), WebAddress: localhost:10011
[INFO] 14:03:50,801 [rpc-client-observation-pool-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10012], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=PartyC, L=Paris, C=FR], platformVersion=4, serial=1558587823477), WebAddress: localhost:10015
```

Comment: did you start the nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes should still be working, those errors are unfortunate and should probably be looked into.

That being said, the reason why you cannot access the web client is probably due to you not running them.

From the example page:

> Each Spring Boot server needs to be started in its own terminal/command prompt, replace X with A, B and C:
>
> Unix/Mac OSX: ./gradlew runPartyXServer
> Windows: gradlew.bat runPartyXServer

Or in intellij you can go to `clients/build.gradle`, scroll to the bottom and client the run button next to the server configs.

Doing this will run the webservers and allow you to interact with the nodes.

Comment: t was thanks to you that we were able to solve it.Thank you so much!